# Calculate performance based on rating in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a table for Sales with revenue each day and another table for Rating which is used to calculate the performance based on revenue milestone

```
CREATE TABLE #Rating(
    [Revenue] int NULL,
    [Percentage] float NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into [#Rating] select 20000, 1.1
insert into [#Rating] select 30000, 1.2
insert into [#Rating] select 40000, 1.3

CREATE TABLE #Sales(
    [Date] datetime,
    [Revenue] int NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into #Sales select '2017-01-01', 7000
insert into #Sales select '2017-01-02', 22000
insert into #Sales select '2017-01-03', 33000
insert into #Sales select '2017-01-04', 46000
insert into #Sales select '2017-01-05', 50000
```

We would like to evaluate the sales performance based on rating. For instance,

If Revenue reaches 20000 milestone, performance = revenue * 1.0

If Revenue reaches 30000 milestone, performance = revenue * 1.1

So the final performance should be as follow

```
Date, Revenue, Performance
'2017-01-01', 7000, 7000
'2017-01-02', 22000, 24200
'2017-01-03', 33000, 39600
'2017-01-04', 46000, 59800
'2017-01-05', 50000, 65000
```

May I know how to setup the query for the matching? Thanks

[Edited to revise the wordings]

Comment: Not really clear what you need here, I would recommend to join sales with rating but there isn't a clear explanation about the `between 20000 and 30000` association should be between the two tables.

Comment: The Rating table refers to the milestone. If Revenue reach 20000 milestone, performance = Revenue * 1.1. If revenue reach 30000, performance = Revenue * 1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two simplest ways to achieve this are with a subquery in your select statement or an outer apply. For example:

```
SELECT S.[Date],
       S.Revenue, 
       Performance = S.Revenue * COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 R.Percentage FROM #Rating AS R WHERE R.Revenue <= S.Revenue ORDER BY R.Revenue DESC), 1)
FROM #Sales S;
```

Or...

```
SELECT S.[Date],
       S.Revenue, 
       Performance = S.Revenue * COALESCE(R.Percentage, 1)
FROM #Sales S
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 R.Percentage FROM #Rating AS R WHERE R.Revenue <= S.Revenue ORDER BY R.Revenue DESC) AS R;
```

Note: You could probably use `MAX(R.Percentage)` instead of `TOP 1` (leaving out the `ORDER BY R.Revenue DESC` as well), since it's unlikely the percentage would go down with an increase in revenue.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 Select S.Date
       ,S.Revenue
       ,(   (Select Max(R.Percentage)
             From Rating R
             Where S.Revenue < R.Revenue)
         * S.Revenue) as Performance
 From Sales S
```

Comment: It does not work and returns NULL for records on 4-Jan and 5-Jan because the Revenue is larger

Answer (score 0):

First get the Performance Rating table in a way such that each record has Range and corresponding Rating. 
Then join the Sales data based on the Performance Range and calculate the final performance.

```
with 
RangePerformance as 
( 
select lag(Revenue, 1, 0) over (order by Revenue) LowVal, Revenue HighVal, Percentage 
from Rating
)
select  sales.Date, sales.Revenue, sales.Revenue*RangePerformance.Percentage
from sales 
join RangePerformance 
on sales.Revenue between RangePerformance.LowVal and RangePerformance.HighVal
```

Breaking it down

```
select lag(Revenue, 1, 0) over (order by Revenue) LowVal, Revenue HighVal, Percentage 
from Rating
```

will give you the intermediate result set:

```
0     20000 1.1
20000 30000 1.2
30000 40000 1.3
```

Then join this result set to Sales table based on Join condition of Sales Revenue falling within any range in above set.

Comment: I cannot test it as I don't have SQL Server 2012 or above. But I think it do not work if Revenue is larger than 40000